# jQuery UI dialog - cannot insert table in dialog contents

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, datatables

I have a simple web page where for each row of data, I can pop up a jQuery UI dialog with the details of that row. Since there can be multiple rows in the sub-query a table is the best choice. The result is that I get an empty dialog box, and the table contained in that div (the one for the dialog) appears at the bottom of the page, whether the row is clicked to activate the dialog. Everything else works perfectly, the event for the click, the dialog popup, the passing of the right id for the div, all perfect.

But the dang table (the one inside the dialog, with the class of 'inner-table') appears at the bottom of the page, right off the bat.

The HTML is created in Groovy, with the HTMLMarkupBuilder, and the resulting HTML looks like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NAS Execution Groovy Servlet</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/executions.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css'></link>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery-ui.css'></link>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/nas.css'></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='results' class='execution-results'>
      <p id='rpt-header'>
        <span class='rpt-header-txt'>Backup Schedule Report for </span>
        <span class='rpt-header-asset'>ret2w089n1t1</span>
      </p>
      <table id='nas-table'>
        <thead>
          <tr class='table-header'>
            <th class='hidden'>Backup ID</th>
            <th>Schedule Name</th>
            <th>Backup Product</th>
            <th>Size Mb</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Expiration Date</th>
            <th>Mon 17</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class='row'>
            <td class='hidden'>12345678</td>
            <td class='row-data'>null</td>
            <td class='row-data'>Product One</td>
            <td id='size-mb' class='row-data'>601.31</td>
            <td class='row-data'>00:09:03</td>
            <td class='row-data'>158 secs</td>
            <td class='row-data'>2012-10-01</td>
            <td class='row-center'>
              <img id='success-fail' src='img/success.gif'></img>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class='row'>
            <td class='hidden'>23456789</td>
            <td class='row-data'>PolicyName</td>
            <td class='row-data'>Product Two</td>
            <td id='size-mb' class='row-data'>995.92</td>
            <td class='row-data'>20:09:00</td>
            <td class='row-data'>191 secs</td>
            <td class='row-data'>2012-10-01</td>
            <td class='row-center'>
              <img id='success-fail' src='img/success.gif'></img>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <div id='dialog-23456789' class='details-dialog'>
            <table class='inner-table'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>JOB_TYPE_NAME</th>
                  <th>VENDOR_STATUS_NAME</th>
                  <th>KILOBYTES</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Incr Backup</td>
                  <td>Successful</td>
                  <td>1019821</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The jQuery for this is pretty simple; it uses the id from the row clicked on, and pops up a dialog window. That works fine, but the table that is contained in that div is actually at the bottom of the screen, even before anything is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nas-table').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
         "aaSorting": [[4, 'asc']]
    }   );


    $('.row').live("click", function(){
        var target = $(this);
        var backupId = $(this).children(":first").html();
        var thisId = '#dialog-' + backupId;
        $(thisId).dialog(
            {   
                title: "Backup Job Detail",
                width: 800,
                height: 450
            }
        );
        $(thisId).dialog("open");
        $(thisId).dialog("widget").position({
                my: 'left top',
                at: 'left bottom',
                of: target
        });
    });

} );
```

At first, I thought the Groovy HTMLMarkupBuilder was outputting the DOM before everything happened, but when I do a view source, copy it to a file, and open the file in my browser, I get the same result.

I would appreciate any help with this. I asked this question earlier, in case you want to complain about that, but I had to follow up some other potential issues in the Groovy code, which I resolved. This example is more complete, and represents exactly what my code will do.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a div nested within a table outside of a TR and TD, which will cause the rendering and DOM to be a bit wrong. If you adjust the html so that it resembles something like this it will work:

```
<div id='results' class='execution-results'> 
      <p id='rpt-header'> 
        <span class='rpt-header-txt'>Backup Schedule Report for </span> 
        <span class='rpt-header-asset'>ret2w089n1t1</span> 
      </p> 
      <table id='nas-table'> 
        <thead> 
          <tr class='table-header'> 
            <th class='hidden'>Backup ID</th> 
            <th>Schedule Name</th> 
            <th>Backup Product</th> 
            <th>Size Mb</th> 
            <th>Start Time</th> 
            <th>Duration</th> 
            <th>Expiration Date</th> 
            <th>Mon 17</th> 
          </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
          <tr class='row'> 
            <td class='hidden'>12345678</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>null</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>Product One</td> 
            <td id='size-mb' class='row-data'>601.31</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>00:09:03</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>158 secs</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>2012-10-01</td> 
            <td class='row-center'> 
              <img id='success-fail' src='img/success.gif'></img> 
            </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr class='row'> 
            <td class='hidden'>23456789</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>PolicyName</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>Product Two</td> 
            <td id='size-mb' class='row-data'>995.92</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>20:09:00</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>191 secs</td> 
            <td class='row-data'>2012-10-01</td> 
            <td class='row-center'> 
              <img id='success-fail' src='img/success.gif'></img> 
            </td> 
          </tr>
          </tbody> 
      </table>
          <div id='dialog-23456789' class='details-dialog' style="display:none;"> 
            <table class='inner-table'> 
              <thead> 
                <tr> 
                  <th>JOB_TYPE_NAME</th> 
                  <th>VENDOR_STATUS_NAME</th> 
                  <th>KILOBYTES</th> 
                </tr> 
              </thead> 
              <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                  <td>Incr Backup</td> 
                  <td>Successful</td> 
                  <td>1019821</td> 
                </tr> 
              </tbody> 
            </table> 
          </div>         
    </div>
```

The trick is to move the div outside of the parent table and also you need to set the display:none on the details table or it will be shown when the page is rendered.

Comment: I wondered about that myself, but since I'm building the HTML as I go I figured I had to do it the way I did. I'll add the HTML to a List in the Groovy code and render it under the table, as you say. Thanks so much for helping.